# turn a hx-get text into an url

Tags: jinja2, htmx

How can I get urls to change to text, the hx-get works fine but with dead text to click:

```
<span hx-get="/runschedule/{{job['project_id']}}/{{k}}?name={{job['project_name']}}-{{v['name']}}&text=true" \
title="click to schedule {{k}}">{{v['name']}}</span>
```

like below, but changing to text without following the url:

```
<a href="/runschedule/{{job['project_id']}}/{{k}}?name={{job['project_name']}}-{{v['name']}}&text=true" \
title="click to schedule {{k}}">{{v['name']}}</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a JS event handler that cancels the default behavior of the hyperlink.

Try this:

```html
<a href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault();" \
hx-get="/runschedule/{{job['project_id']}}/{{k}}?name={{job['project_name']}}-{{v['name']}}&text=true" \
title="click to schedule {{k}}">{{v['name']}}</a>
```